# How to Align an image to the right corner in list row using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to align an image to the right size of a list row in Swift/SwiftUI.

```swift
List {
    Image(systemName: "pencil")
}
```

I've tried adding several different alignment tags but none seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you wanted this (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1):

[image: demo]

```
List {
    Image(systemName: "pencil")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
}
```

Comment: This seems to just place the Image around the middle of the row instead of the end. Is it possible it's because I'm using `.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())`?

Comment: See updated with tested code demo (included list style). Maybe you use different code? Or different dev environment?

Answer (score 10):

Put it in a HStack and add a spacer.

```
List {
     HStack {
           Spacer()
           Image(systemName: "pencil")
     }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to align it fully to the right.

Comment: @Lemon then you have to use scrollview , cause the List cell has a padding , content only lay inside it. But you can use offset with List-this is not a good practice

Comment: @Yodagama If it's really this hard to align something slightly to the right I'm scared 